# Error applying patch with Git

Tags: 7, version-control

I have read different SE posts and Drupal.org posts about applying patches using git but I am getting an error message whenever I try any of the following methods. the error is:

> error: modules/callbacks.inc: No such file or directory

I tried:

```
curl https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/op_update_should_be_create-2807275-2.patch | git apply -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   668  100   668    0     0   2278      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2279
error: modules/callbacks.inc: No such file or directory
```

Also, I downloaded the patch into Drupal root and tried:

```
git apply -v op_update_should_be_create-2807275-2.patch
```

The backstory:
I was getting the following errors on my website, which I found [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2807275) explaining that it was because of Entity API, and I was trying to apply the patch in #2.

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$custom in
>   block_block_list_alter() (line 794 of
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/example/docroot/modules/block/block.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$visibility in
>   block_block_list_alter() (line 807 of
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/example/docroot/modules/block/block.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$pages in
>   block_block_list_alter() (line 817 of
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/example/docroot/modules/block/block.module).

This is my first time trying to apply a patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place **op_update_should_be_create-2807275-2.patch** into the module folder, in this case being the `sites/all/modules/entity` folder.

Then in your terminal `cd` (change directory) into the module folder.

`cd /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/entity`

then

`git apply -v op_update_should_be_create-2807275-2.patch`

In the [discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2807275), Fago has commited this patch (2 months ago), but into the 7.x-.1.x only.

[image]

So I assume you're trying to patch the stable version, 7.x-1.8.

If you use/download the latest dev (7.x-1.x-dev) version, it will already have the patch.

**Note:** The rule of thumb, is to use the Stable version rather than the Dev version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I check and I am already on 1.8 version. So I guess that means that this patch isn't the answer I need.

Comment: @Christia you misunderstood. The 1.8 version does not have the patch yet (as the commit was made 2 months ago to the 1.x, the 1.8 was released 5 months ago, which means it does not have the patch, so you need to apply the patch to the 1.8.

Comment: I counted the months wrong, 1.8 was released 7 months ago, but yeah you get my point `:)`